# Full page banner in Genesis Wordpress framework?

Tags: css, wordpress, slider, layered, genesis

I'm building a website using the Genesis framework for WordPress.

I just want a simple full-wdidth responsive layered banner but in Genesis this is always forced into the container div, which obviously isn't full-width.

Layered is also important - it needs a background, and elements layered on top.

Is there a 'correct' way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should hook into the `genesis_before_header` call and put what you need there, then style it with HTML/CSS as needed:

```
add_action( 'genesis_before_header', 'genesis_banner_header' );
function genesis_banner_header() {
     get_template_part( 'inc/banner' );
}
```

In the example above you should create a file called banner.php and drop it into a folder called /inc in your theme or child theme and add your HTML there.  I always find this simpler than jamming all the HTML directly into the function.